# How does activerecord change model associations in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, rails-admin

I at one point had a simple model where a recipe had many photos, yet I was only creating Recipe objects by setting one photo through carrierwave on the recipe.photo attribute rather than through recipe.photos.

This was in part because I didn't realize I had specified has_many. I was creating Recipe objects through rails_admin gem by assigning to the recipe.photo attribute rather than recipe.photos.

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :content, presence: true
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :photos, class_name: 'RecipePhoto', dependent: :destroy
  mount_uploader :photo, RecipePhotoUploader
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, allow_destroy: :true
end

class RecipePhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  mount_uploader :photo, RecipePhotoUploader
end
```

So my question is when I began assigning to recipe.photos and then were to access a recipe instances photos via recipe.photos

I would only see photos that were created onto recipe.photos, and not recipe.photo.

Why is this? Shouldn't ActiveRecord access ALL associated photos to the recipe with notation recipe.photos?

Why does it treat it as recipe.photo were assigned via a has_one relationship even though it was has_many the whole time?

Shouldn't ActiveRecord be robust to changing relationships? Like if it at a later date and wanted to change it to has_one, etc.

Comment: Can you post the migration which you would have written to transfer data from `recipe.photo` to `recipe.photos`?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean a bit? The underlying database tables don't change, only the ActiveRecord associations specified in the model files.

Comment: It looks like `Recipe` has both an association to `photos` and an attribute of `photo`. So when you call `photos` you will get all the associated `RecipePhoto` objects, but calling `photo` will get you the `photo` attribute for this recipe. This is not a bad design if you want to have a "main photo" for the recipe although I think I would name it something different to avoid confusion.

Comment: How could I change it though? Because carrierwave works by mounting itself onto a specified attribute via the Uploader class, and I don't want to create a new field for the many and keep the existing for the has_one.